# What the error "StatusCode cannot be set because the response has already started" in ASP.NET does mean?

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-core, http-post, http-get

I try to run one method named PostGet:

```
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc;
using Jint;
using WebApplication1.Program;

namespace WebApplication1.Controllers
{
[Route("/{endpoint}")]
public class HomeController : ProgramMain
{
    Engine _engine = new Engine();

    [HttpGet]
    [HttpPost]
    public async Task<int[]> PostGet([FromQuery] int[] options)
    {
        string endpoint = string.Empty;

        try
        {
            endpoint = "/" + RouteData.Values["endpoint"].ToString();
            int i = 0;
            for (; i < _endpoints.Length; i++)
            {
                if (_endpoints[i] == endpoint)
                {
                    Console.WriteLine("Endpoint: " + endpoint);
                    break;
                }

                if (i == _endpoints.Length - 1)
                {
                    return null;
                }
            }

            var fromValue = _engine.Execute("function " + _scripts[i] + "(option) " +
                "{ return option; }").GetValue(_scripts[i]);

            foreach (var option in options)
                Console.Write(fromValue.Call(option) + "\t");

            Console.WriteLine();

            StreamReader reader = new StreamReader("html/index-2.html");
            string content = await reader.ReadToEndAsync();
            Response.ContentType = "text/html;charset=utf-8";
            await Response.WriteAsync(content);
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(ex.Message);
        }

        return options;
    }
}
```

}

But come up with errors:

fail: Microsoft.AspNetCore.Diagnostics.DeveloperExceptionPageMiddleware[1]
An unhandled exception has occurred while executing the request.
System.InvalidOperationException: StatusCode cannot be set because the response has already started.
at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Server.Kestrel.Core.Internal.Http.HttpProtocol.ThrowResponseAlreadyStartedException(String value)
at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Server.Kestrel.Core.Internal.Http.HttpProtocol.set_StatusCode(Int32 value)
at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Server.Kestrel.Core.Internal.Http.HttpProtocol.Microsoft.AspNetCore.Http.Features.IHttpResponseFeature.set_StatusCode(Int32 value)
at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Http.DefaultHttpResponse.set_StatusCode(Int32 value)
at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Infrastructure.ObjectResultExecutor.ExecuteAsyncCore(ActionContext context, ObjectResult result, Type objectType, Object value)
at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Infrastructure.ObjectResultExecutor.ExecuteAsync(ActionContext context, ObjectResult result)
at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.ObjectResult.ExecuteResultAsync(ActionContext context)
at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Infrastructure.ResourceInvoker.InvokeResultAsync(IActionResult result)
at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Infrastructure.ResourceInvoker.ResultNext[TFilter,TFilterAsync](State& next, Scope& scope, Object& state, Boolean& isCompleted)
at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Infrastructure.ResourceInvoker.InvokeResultFilters()
--- End of stack trace from previous location ---
at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Infrastructure.ResourceInvoker.g__Awaited|20_0(ResourceInvoker invoker, Task lastTask, State next, Scope scope, Object state, Boolean isCompleted)
at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Infrastructure.ResourceInvoker.g__Awaited|17_0(ResourceInvoker invoker, Task task, IDisposable scope)
at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Infrastructure.ResourceInvoker.g__Awaited|17_0(ResourceInvoker invoker, Task task, IDisposable scope)
at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Routing.EndpointMiddleware.g__AwaitRequestTask|6_0(Endpoint endpoint, Task requestTask, ILogger logger)
at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Diagnostics.DeveloperExceptionPageMiddleware.Invoke(HttpContext context)
warn: Microsoft.AspNetCore.Diagnostics.DeveloperExceptionPageMiddleware[2]
The response has already started, the error page middleware will not be executed.
fail: Microsoft.AspNetCore.Server.Kestrel[13]
Connection id "0HN23TU8ON6JK", Request id "0HN23TU8ON6JK:00000003": An unhandled exception was thrown by the application.
System.InvalidOperationException: StatusCode cannot be set because the response has already started.
at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Server.Kestrel.Core.Internal.Http.HttpProtocol.ThrowResponseAlreadyStartedException(String value)
at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Server.Kestrel.Core.Internal.Http.HttpProtocol.set_StatusCode(Int32 value)
at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Server.Kestrel.Core.Internal.Http.HttpProtocol.Microsoft.AspNetCore.Http.Features.IHttpResponseFeature.set_StatusCode(Int32 value)
at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Http.DefaultHttpResponse.set_StatusCode(Int32 value)
at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Infrastructure.ObjectResultExecutor.ExecuteAsyncCore(ActionContext context, ObjectResult result, Type objectType, Object value)
at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Infrastructure.ObjectResultExecutor.ExecuteAsync(ActionContext context, ObjectResult result)
at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.ObjectResult.ExecuteResultAsync(ActionContext context)
at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Infrastructure.ResourceInvoker.InvokeResultAsync(IActionResult result)
at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Infrastructure.ResourceInvoker.ResultNext[TFilter,TFilterAsync](State& next, Scope& scope, Object& state, Boolean& isCompleted)
at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Infrastructure.ResourceInvoker.InvokeResultFilters()
--- End of stack trace from previous location ---
at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Infrastructure.ResourceInvoker.g__Awaited|20_0(ResourceInvoker invoker, Task lastTask, State next, Scope scope, Object state, Boolean isCompleted)
at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Infrastructure.ResourceInvoker.g__Awaited|17_0(ResourceInvoker invoker, Task task, IDisposable scope)
at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Infrastructure.ResourceInvoker.g__Awaited|17_0(ResourceInvoker invoker, Task task, IDisposable scope)
at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Routing.EndpointMiddleware.g__AwaitRequestTask|6_0(Endpoint endpoint, Task requestTask, ILogger logger)
at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Diagnostics.DeveloperExceptionPageMiddleware.Invoke(HttpContext context)
at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Diagnostics.DeveloperExceptionPageMiddleware.Invoke(HttpContext context)
at Microsoft.WebTools.BrowserLink.Net.BrowserLinkMiddleware.ExecuteWithFilterAsync(IHttpSocketAdapter injectScriptSocket, String requestId, HttpContext httpContext)
at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Watch.BrowserRefresh.BrowserRefreshMiddleware.InvokeAsync(HttpContext context)
at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Server.Kestrel.Core.Internal.Http.HttpProtocol.ProcessRequests[TContext](IHttpApplication`1 application)
Endpoint: /test-get

warn: Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Infrastructure.ObjectResultExecutor[1]
No output formatter was found for content types 'text/html;charset=utf-8, text/html;charset=utf-8' to write the response.
fail: Microsoft.AspNetCore.Diagnostics.DeveloperExceptionPageMiddleware[1]
An unhandled exception has occurred while executing the request.
System.InvalidOperationException: StatusCode cannot be set because the response has already started.
at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Server.Kestrel.Core.Internal.Http.HttpProtocol.ThrowResponseAlreadyStartedException(String value)
at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Server.Kestrel.Core.Internal.Http.HttpProtocol.set_StatusCode(Int32 value)
at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Server.Kestrel.Core.Internal.Http.HttpProtocol.Microsoft.AspNetCore.Http.Features.IHttpResponseFeature.set_StatusCode(Int32 value)
at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Http.DefaultHttpResponse.set_StatusCode(Int32 value)
at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Infrastructure.ObjectResultExecutor.ExecuteAsyncCore(ActionContext context, ObjectResult result, Type objectType, Object value)
at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Infrastructure.ObjectResultExecutor.ExecuteAsync(ActionContext context, ObjectResult result)
at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.ObjectResult.ExecuteResultAsync(ActionContext context)
at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Infrastructure.ResourceInvoker.InvokeResultAsync(IActionResult result)
at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Infrastructure.ResourceInvoker.ResultNext[TFilter,TFilterAsync](State& next, Scope& scope, Object& state, Boolean& isCompleted)
at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Infrastructure.ResourceInvoker.InvokeResultFilters()
--- End of stack trace from previous location ---
at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Infrastructure.ResourceInvoker.g__Awaited|20_0(ResourceInvoker invoker, Task lastTask, State next, Scope scope, Object state, Boolean isCompleted)
at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Infrastructure.ResourceInvoker.g__Awaited|17_0(ResourceInvoker invoker, Task task, IDisposable scope)
at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Infrastructure.ResourceInvoker.g__Awaited|17_0(ResourceInvoker invoker, Task task, IDisposable scope)
at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Routing.EndpointMiddleware.g__AwaitRequestTask|6_0(Endpoint endpoint, Task requestTask, ILogger logger)
at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Diagnostics.DeveloperExceptionPageMiddleware.Invoke(HttpContext context)
warn: Microsoft.AspNetCore.Diagnostics.DeveloperExceptionPageMiddleware[2]
The response has already started, the error page middleware will not be executed.
fail: Microsoft.AspNetCore.Server.Kestrel[13]
Connection id "0HN23TU8ON6JK", Request id "0HN23TU8ON6JK:00000005": An unhandled exception was thrown by the application.
System.InvalidOperationException: StatusCode cannot be set because the response has already started.
at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Server.Kestrel.Core.Internal.Http.HttpProtocol.ThrowResponseAlreadyStartedException(String value)
at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Server.Kestrel.Core.Internal.Http.HttpProtocol.set_StatusCode(Int32 value)
at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Server.Kestrel.Core.Internal.Http.HttpProtocol.Microsoft.AspNetCore.Http.Features.IHttpResponseFeature.set_StatusCode(Int32 value)
at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Http.DefaultHttpResponse.set_StatusCode(Int32 value)
at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Infrastructure.ObjectResultExecutor.ExecuteAsyncCore(ActionContext context, ObjectResult result, Type objectType, Object value)
at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Infrastructure.ObjectResultExecutor.ExecuteAsync(ActionContext context, ObjectResult result)
at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.ObjectResult.ExecuteResultAsync(ActionContext context)
at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Infrastructure.ResourceInvoker.InvokeResultAsync(IActionResult result)
at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Infrastructure.ResourceInvoker.ResultNext[TFilter,TFilterAsync](State& next, Scope& scope, Object& state, Boolean& isCompleted)
at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Infrastructure.ResourceInvoker.InvokeResultFilters()
--- End of stack trace from previous location ---
at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Infrastructure.ResourceInvoker.g__Awaited|20_0(ResourceInvoker invoker, Task lastTask, State next, Scope scope, Object state, Boolean isCompleted)
at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Infrastructure.ResourceInvoker.g__Awaited|17_0(ResourceInvoker invoker, Task task, IDisposable scope)
at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Infrastructure.ResourceInvoker.g__Awaited|17_0(ResourceInvoker invoker, Task task, IDisposable scope)
at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Routing.EndpointMiddleware.g__AwaitRequestTask|6_0(Endpoint endpoint, Task requestTask, ILogger logger)
at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Diagnostics.DeveloperExceptionPageMiddleware.Invoke(HttpContext context)
at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Diagnostics.DeveloperExceptionPageMiddleware.Invoke(HttpContext context)
at Microsoft.WebTools.BrowserLink.Net.BrowserLinkMiddleware.ExecuteWithFilterAsync(IHttpSocketAdapter injectScriptSocket, String requestId, HttpContext httpContext)
at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Watch.BrowserRefresh.BrowserRefreshMiddleware.InvokeAsync(HttpContext context)
at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Server.Kestrel.Core.Internal.Http.HttpProtocol.ProcessRequests[TContext](IHttpApplication`1 application)

Comment: You write to the response and then return options, which will try to create and return another response, which fails, because you already wrote to the response. Figure out what api this endpoint should have. Then implement it.

Comment: Unrelated: I think you would benefit from introducing actual logging instead of doing `Console.WriteLine`s.

Comment: And: I'd also recommend to use exception handling Middleware that logs instead of try/ catch. As is, errors are hidden to the client. A quick fix would be to just `throw;` after logging the error, but having a Middleware handling it completely would be idiomatic.

Comment: @Fildor First I need to open index-2.html using Get and after that open a new page with the array using Post to send the data from index-2.html fields. My task is to use one function for Get and Post, without separating. How can I do that?

Comment: Can you provide a simple complete example to explain how to reproduce the problem you are encountering?